# NSURLConnection gets data from unknown HTML page

Tags: php, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I have a class that creates a NSURLConnection with the class set as the delegate. The connection sends a request to our server to get back a list of data. Everything has been working great except one day, the delegate function (didReceiveData:) returned an unknown HTML page (the page seems to come from a third party website, i.e. it is not a PHP error page from our server).

I amended my code to ignore any data that does not look like the kind I am expecting, but I am curious at to how in hell would my NSURLConnection gets the HMTL content of an unknown website??

Comment: Please add the relevant code to help troubleshoot.

Comment: Sorry I cannot add the code but it is just plain vanilla NSURLConnection call to our server URL address with a list of parameters. There is nothing in my code that relates to the webpage I got back. Just wondered if anybody ever experienced this.